# What do I need to install to use fwupd to update my computer's firmware?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firmware

Running Ubuntu 19.10.

Have installed fwupd from the snap store as follows:

command:

```
sudo snap install --classic fwupd
```

result:

```
Setup snap "fwupd" (1501) security profiles                                                                                            
fwupd 1.3.6 from Richard Hughes installed
```

I'm trying to follow the basic usage flow to update firmware, as documented here: https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd. I can't get past the first step:

```
sudo fwupdmgr get-devices
Unsupported daemon version 1.3.6, client version is 1.2.10
```

It would seem I need to update the client, but I'm not sure how do that.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to either run:

```
fwupd.fwupdmgr get-devices
```

if you have both the snap and deb versions installed on your machine,

Or, in my case, I removed the snap version, purged, then reinstalled the deb version and all worked again as normal:

```
sudo snap remove fwupd
sudo apt-get purge fwupd
sudo apt-get install fwupd
```

I had to reinstall fwupd because I was still getting errors after removing the snap version.

Comment: This worked for me. Howver, When purging the package I had to manually remove a folder in `/var/lib/` with `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/fwupd`. I don't know if it makes a difference but I did it just in case.